# Como obtener valor de un link que esta dentro de un iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   <div id="dinamico" class="row">
     <div class="col-12">
       <iframe class="test" src="https://www.navexterno.com" min-height="70px" width="100%" frameborder="none"></iframe>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Este `iFrame` contiene un menú con 2 enlaces, dentro de las etiquetas `nav`, `ul`, `li` están mis enlaces, que son:

```
<a id="enlace1" href="google.com">Google</a>
<a id="enlace2" href="youtube.com">Youtube</a>
```

Y en mi sitio donde esta puesto el `iFrame` tengo estos enlaces

```
<a id="enlace-dinamico1" href="#">Google</a>
<a id="enlace-dinamico2" href="#">Youtube</a>
```

Ahora bien quisiera saber como puedo obtener los enlaces 1 y 2 `(href)` que se encuentran dentro del `iframe` y asignarlos a los enlaces dinámicos 1 y 2 que se encuentran en el sitio estático.

**Intenté**:

```
var enlace-d = $("#enlace1").attr("href");
```

**también intente con**:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById("enlace1");
var href_val = anchor.getAttribute("href");
```

Y tampoco selecciona el enlace.

Imagen de ayuda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si es otro dominio puede que el navegador no te deje acceder

Comment: de hecho si esta usando https puede que te de conflictos de seguridad!

Answer (score 0):

En el evento de load, de tu IFrame, deberias consultar su contenido, entre ese contenido, los a

html

```
<iframe id="myFrame1" class="test" src="https://www.navexterno.com" min-height="70px" width="100%" frameborder="none"></iframe>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myFrame1').on('load', function() {
                var elementA = $(this).contents().find("#enlace1").attr('href');
                alert(elementA);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Solo aparece undefined.

Comment: prueba reemplazando .prop por .attr

Answer (score 0):

Intenta asi, para obetener, los valores de todas las `a` presionadas,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("a").click(function(event) {
              var href = $(this).attr('href');
              alert('valor del href' + href);

          });

        });
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Me obtiene solo el primer enlace y cuando le inento poner un id para que lo seleccione me aparece undefined.

Comment: Me obtiene solo el primer enlace y cuando le inento poner un id para que lo seleccione me aparece undefined. `var href = $("a#enlace1").attr('href');` o `var href = $("#enlace1").attr('href');`.

Comment: que raro, por que yo lo probe y me otiene los dos

Comment: en que momento quieres desencadenar el evento ?

Comment: Al momento en que la pagina y el iframe terminen de cargar.
`$("#enlace1").attr('href');` esto funciona pero solo si estoy en la pagina del iframe. Ya cuando pongo el codigo en el sitio donde estar el iframe, no obtiene nada.

Comment: No entendi esto `Ya cuando pongo el codigo en el sitio donde estar el iframe, no obtiene nada` ??? me perdi

Comment: Mira tengo mi Iframe que carga la pagina : https://www.navexterno.com 
ahora si yo me voy a la pagina https://www.navexterno.com y pruebo tu codigo, si funciona. 
ahora me voy a la pagina principal donde puse el iframe que contiene la pagina https://www.navexterno.com. y ahi ejecutando el codigo en la pagina principal no me obtiene nada.

Answer (score 0):

Como me lo suponía si no es el mismo dominio no te deja

```js
var iFrame = document.getElementById("elframe");


iFrame.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var enlaces = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.querySelectorAll('a');

    console.log(enlaces);
  });
```

```css
iframe {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 320px;
  height: 340px;
}
```

```html
<iframe id="elframe" src="https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeId');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

La variable `innerDoc` va a contener el contenido de el iframe por tanto ahi podés usar un selector para obtener todos los links, ej

```
innerDoc.getElementsByClassName('links')
```

Suponiendo que todos los links de ese iframe tienen la clase link